# malloc sometimes returns memory ASAN reports is poisoned

Tags: c, malloc, address-sanitizer

***Background***

OS: `5.17.11-1rodete2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.17.11-1rodete2 (2022-06-09) x86_64`

GCC: `gcc (Debian 11.3.0-3) 11.3.0`

While executing a benchmark where there is heavy execution of `malloc()`, I encountered an assertion failure that I previously thought was impossible:

```
p = malloc(size);
assert(!__asan_region_is_poisoned(p,size));
```

If the assertion isn't there, ASAN will instead report that the the memory returned by `malloc` is user-poisoned memory. While the code being benchmarked does use `__asan_unpoison_memory_region` and `__asan_poison_memory_region` elsewhere, there are no such calls in between the `malloc()` and the usage of the memory returned from it.

***Question***

Is this expected behavior, or is it a bug / limit of ASAN once memory addresses returned by `malloc()` start to be recycled?

Comment: Perhaps the bug is in your own code: heap corruption, and that is the first place to look before suspecting the tools.

Comment: what if `p` is NULL

Comment: If you haven't you may want to give valgrind a whirl.

Comment: We need to see your code and your compilation options. If you explicitly poison a region you probably need to explicitly unpoison it before doing  `free` on it

Comment: @0___________ - the code shown here is abbreviated for brevity; for the purposes of understanding the expected behavior of ASAN, you can assume that `p` is never `NULL`.

@AllanWind - I may try Valgrind, but with this question I was looking to better understand the expected behavior of ASAN.

@CraigEstey - interesting. I'll follow up to see if we're pairing every poison to an unpoison before freeing.